# jqPlot - Pie legend too tall when there are many legend items

Tags: jqplot

I'm using jqPlot to create a pie chart with a legend.  Part of my jqPlot pie options look as follows:

```
seriesDefaults: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
    rendererOptions: {
        padding: 10,
        showDataLabels: true,
        dataLabelFormatString: '%.2f%%',
        sliceMargin: 2,
        startAngle: -90
    }
},
legend: {
    show: true,
    location: 'e',
    placement: 'outside',
    xoffset: 1,
    fontSize: '11px',
    rowSpacing: '10px',
    textColor: '#222222',
    fontFamily: 'Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif'
}
```

Recently I've come across a case where there are many legend items (e.g., 21), which makes my legend box too tall.  I'm wondering if there is a way to either

1. have a vertical scroll bar within the legend box
2. display the legend items in multiple columns (preferable)

I've tried setting the following properties:

- numberRows
- numberColumns

which I found from this page:

[$.jqplot.PieRenderer options](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pieRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.PieLegendRenderer.numberRows)

however they don't seem to make any changes.

Would anybody be able to provide me with a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to go with the provided column/row settings. I double-checked personally that this settings do work. Just make sure that in legend you set the `numberColumns` or `numberRows` inside `rendererOptions`, like:

```
legend: { 
  show: true, 
  location: 'ne',
  rendererOptions: {numberColumns: 2}
}
```

If this doesn't work then I must say some other bug must be hiding in your code, then let us see the code so we can find and squash the bug together :)

Comment: It's worked!  Silly me, I was adding "numberColumns" outside of rendererOptions.  Thanks for your help!  Much appreciated.

Comment: No worries. I did the same mistake once. Now I always double check the doc and examples to be certain. In this particular case from doc itself you think that it should go just under the legend :)

Comment: Just for testing!, if you need to limit the rows the property is numberRows:

legend: { 
  show: true, 
  location: 'ne',
  rendererOptions: {numberRrows: 20}
}